# Deserialize JSON array into string array

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

Say I have a `string` representing an array of objects in JSON form:

```
string s = "[{\"name\":\"Person1\"},{\"name\":\"Person2\"}]";
```

What I want is an array of strings, each string being the *string representation* of a JSON object - **NOT** the object itself.  It should look something like this:

```
string[] s = new string[]
{
     "{\"name\":\"Person1\"}",
     "{\"name\":\"Person2\"}"
};
```

1) Almost every search I attempt pulls up millions of results on how to simply deserialize a JSON string using (eg) Json.NET.  This is *not* what I want to do.

2) I have tried building a class representing the objects to temporarily loop through a deserialize/serialize mapping each to a string in an array, but the schema for the objects is variable (hence why I only need a string representation).

3) I have attempted a few regex to try and do this, but my JSON string can contain fields that contain JSON strings as their value (icky, but out of my control) and so nested character escaping etc drove me partially mad before I decided to beg for help here.

Surely this should be simple?  Anybody got any pointers?

Comment: Why don't you want to use Json.NET?  You could deserialize to a JSON array and then loop through and serialize each object in the array to a string and put those in a list or what have you.

Comment: I thought that deserializing to `object` (instead of to a class that defined all expected fields), then serializing, would cause fields to be lost.  I considered it for a moment at the very beginning, then immediately dismissed the idea as "clearly not going to work".  Guess the egg is on my face :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to deserialize it, and then serialize each object independently. 
For example (using `Newtonsoft.Json`):

```
string json = "[{\"name\":\"Person1\"},{\"name\":\"Person2\"}]";

var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(json);
var result = objects.Select(obj => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)).ToArray();
```

Yields (as a `string[]`):

```
{"name":"Person1"} 
{"name":"Person2"}
```

If you try to avoid deserializing and serializing, you're almost certain to run into an edge case that will break your code.

Comment: I thought that deserializing to `object` (instead of to a class that defined all expected fields), then serializing, would cause fields to be lost.  I considered it for a moment at the very beginning, then immediately dismissed the idea as "clearly not going to work".  Guess the egg is on my face :)  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "[{\"name\":\"Person1\"},{\"name\":\"Person2\"}]";
var Json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(s);
string[] Jsonn = Json.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

[image: Response from [] Jsonn]

`[] Jsonn` returns string array instead of object array with JObject formatted.

Hope this one help you.

Answer (score -6):

Why don't you just use this

```
string s = "[{\"name\":\"Person1\"},{\"name\":\"Person2\"}]";

string[] t = s.Split(',');
```

I tried it. It simply gives you string array as you want it....

Comment: `but my JSON string can contain fields that contain JSON strings as their value` - won't work

Comment: @Rob Look like you did not see what is expected in string array                                           string[] s = new string[]
{
     "{\"name\":\"Person1\"}",
     "{\"name\":\"Person2\"}"
};

Comment: I most definitely did look at the expected results. Even ignoring the fact that he mentioned commas may be present in the json (and thus cannot simply split on `,`), your code will still return `[{"name` instead of `{"name` and `Person2}]` instead of `Person2}`

Comment: Humm... Guess the person originally who posted the question should take whichever is best....

Comment: You don't parse JSON by splitting on comma. Field values can contain a comma, and the first object can contain multiple fields, also separated by comma.